# How to solve the following equation for $x$: $(3x-1)\ln4 =\ln3+ x\ln5$

Tags: logarithms

$$(3x-1)\ln4 =\ln3+ x\ln5$$
Is there a way to solve this for $x$, without typing everything into a calculator, and getting the value that way?

Comment: $x(3\ln 4-\ln 5)=\ln 3+\ln 4$

Comment: *"Without typing everything into a calculator"* Is an exact value fine? (In this case, a solution containing logarithms), or does it have to an approximate numerical value containing decimals?

Comment: @projectilemotion I mean, at the end we need to find x=0.xxx but maybe some rearranging before that would be nice, that's what I meant

Comment: So, is my deleted answer answering your question?

Comment: @projectilemotion Yes, it was, thank you :) Did you delete it btw?

Answer (score 1):

Intutitively, looking at the form of the equation, the most obvious thing to try is to start by expanding the left hand side:
$$3x\ln{4}-\ln{4}=\ln{3}+x\ln{5}$$
We can rearrange it so that all the terms with $x$ are on one side, and all the constants are on the right hand side.
$$3x\ln{4}-x\ln{5}=\ln{3}+\ln{4}$$
Note that since we rearranged it in the form above, you can now factorize the left hand side.
$$x(3\ln{4}-\ln{5})=\ln{3}+\ln{4}$$
All that remains to do is divide both sides by $3\ln{4}-\ln{5}$:
$$x=\frac{\ln{3}+\ln{4}}{3\ln{4}-\ln{5}}$$

---

Note that you can also [simplify it further](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Logarithmic_identities):

$$x=\frac{\ln{3}+\ln{4}}{3\ln{4}-\ln{5}}=\frac{\ln(3\cdot 4)}{\ln(4^3)-\ln{5}}=\frac{\ln{12}}{\ln{\left(\frac{64}{5}\right)}}$$

Comment: Thank you, and after that just using the calculator?

Comment: Indeed. If you wish to check your answer, you should obtain the following:
$$x\approx 0.97468526$$

Answer (score 0):

it is $$x(3\ln(4)-\ln(5))=\ln(3)+\ln(4)$$

Comment: As posted by another user, but with explanations, 15 minutes earlier. What is this game?